# how to get a textbox value from dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating dynamic div with html elements and i need to get value that textbox
This is my dynamic created content now i need to get the

```
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
  <div id="newtextbox1"> // this id is dynamic id
    <div class="row cells2">
      <div class="cell">
        <label>Patient Name</label>         
        <div class="input-control text full-size">
          <input type="text" id="PatientName1" placeholder="Patient Name"/> // this id is dynamic id
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <label>Patient ICNo</label>
        <div class="input-control text full-size" >
           <input type="text" id="PatientICNo" placeholder="Patient ICNo"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here i am trying to get value in jquery

```
if ($("#TextBoxContainer") != null && $("#TextBoxContainer").length > 0) {
    var count = 1;
    $("#TextBoxContainer").each(function () {
        debugger;
        var Pid = "input#PatientName" + count;
        var childdiv = "div#newtextbox" + count;
        count++;
        var patientname = $(this).closest(childdiv).children(Pid).val();           

    });
}
```

Comment: You can just use `var patientname = $(Pid).val();`

Comment: `closest` traverses through parents while you are using it for children. Removing `.closest(childdiv)` might work

Comment: Dont use `id` attributes (especially like that). Use class names and relative selectors. - `$("#TextBoxContainer").each(function () { var patientname = $(this).find('.myNameTextBoxClass').val(); });`

Comment: thank u all bro is any other option

Comment: I would wrap the `.each()` code in a function that gets called onload and again after the dynamic Element is created. By the way, no need for `var count`. jQuery passed the increment and the Element, in that order, as arguments, like `$('#TextBoxContainer').each(function(increment, Element){var c = increment+1;})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/p9ywL4pm/1/

```js
if ($("#TextBoxContainer") != null && $("#TextBoxContainer").length > 0) {
    var count = 1;
    $("#TextBoxContainer").children().each(function () {
        var Pid = "input#PatientName" + count;
        var patientname = $(this).find(Pid).val();           
        console.log(Pid, patientname);
        count++;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
  <div id="newtextbox1">
    <div class="row cells2">
      <div class="cell">
        <label>Patient Name</label>         
        <div class="input-control text full-size">
          <input type="text" id="PatientName1" placeholder="Patient Name" /> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <label>Patient ICNo</label>
        <div class="input-control text full-size" >
          <input type="text" id="PatientICNo" placeholder="Patient ICNo"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="newtextbox2">
    <div class="row cells2">
      <div class="cell">
        <label>Patient Name</label>         
        <div class="input-control text full-size">
          <input type="text" id="PatientName2" placeholder="Patient Name"/> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <label>Patient ICNo</label>
        <div class="input-control text full-size" >
          <input type="text" id="PatientICNo" placeholder="Patient ICNo"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I considered two child elements inside `#TextBoxContainer` container.

Change the `#PatientICNo` input to

```
<input type="text" class="PatientICNo" placeholder="Patient ICNo"/>
```

Use `class` instead of `ID` because `ID` need to unique.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrOfValue =[];
$('.input-control text full-size [type="text"]').each(function() { arrOfValue .push($(this).val())})
```

The arrOfValue will have all the text, use index to get the value.

Comment: bro dynamically all value i need to push in array

Comment: Yes, the above code will select all the input inside .input-control text full-size  class and loops through to get all text value's. i am using the class selector and attritbute type text.